# NoMethodError: undefined method `arel_table' for Dynamoid:class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-dynamodb

Rails 5.1.7, Ruby 2.3.8, Dynamoid 3.0.0

```
class Address
  include Dynamoid::Document

  table name: :address, key: :address_id, read_capacity: 5, write_capacity: 5

  belongs_to :user   
  belongs_to :company
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address

end
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses

end
```

```
Rails Console:

u = User.find 1
u.address
NoMethodError: undefined method `arel_table' for Address:Class

c = Company.find 1
c.addresses
NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Address:Class
```

Hello, i am trying a actionrecord and dynamoid association and can't get the dynamoid objects from the actionrecord objects. Additionaly dynamoid saves the foreign_ids as array and seems like it pluralizes the belongs_to associations.

```
a = Address.find 1
a.user or a.company #is working.
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i made a big mistake. Dynamoid doesn't support crossover associations. So what i did is:

```
class Address
  include Dynamoid::Document

  table name: :address, key: :address_id, read_capacity: 5, write_capacity: 5

  field :user_id
  field :company_id

  def user
    User.find(self.user_id)
  end
  def company
    Company.find(self.company_id)
  def
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  def address
    Address.find_by_user_id(self.id)
  end
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  def addresses
    Address.where('company_id': self.id)
  end
end
```

Offtopic: And if you wanna store JSON as map in DynamoDB:

init attribut raw like

```
field :metadata, :raw
```

load and safe your JSON string like

```
obj.metadata = JSON.load('unparsed JSON string')
obj.save
```